# Problem in SQL query #1066 - Not unique table/alias

Tags: sql

I have a problem with this query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM code
INNER JOIN relations ON tags.id = relations.tag
INNER JOIN code ON relations.code = code.id
WHERE tags.name LIKE '%value%' 
ORDER BY code.id ASC
```

I get this error:

> 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'code'

Comment: You select twice from the same table without using aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear.  You have mentioned `code` three times in the from clause.  What does `code` refer to?

In your case, I think the solution is to remove all the references.  The first should be the `tags` table -- I think.  The last doesn't seem useful.  So:

```
SELECT *
FROM tags t JOIN
     relations r
     ON t.id = r.tag JOIN
     code cr
     ON r.code = cr.id 
WHERE t.name LIKE '%value%'
ORDER BY t.id ASC;
```

Note that I introduced table aliases.  If you do need a second reference to `code`, you can just give it a new alias.